# Link colors. How can I change them only in the index?

Tags: pdftex, hyperref

I am using the package pdftex. Everything is ok, but I would like to have my index references (`\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures`, `\listoftables`) in black and when I changed `linkcolor=Black`, the other links in the book also change. Is there a way, to have only the index in black and the rest of the links in blue?
Thanks!

```
\usepackage[pdftex, bookmarksnumbered, pagebackref, colorlinks=true,
            citecolor=red, linkcolor=DarkBlue, urlcolor=cyan, 
            bookmarksopen]{hyperref}
```